# IS-IS Protocol Configuration on Router does not seem Possible

Tags: networking, protocols, router, cisco, cisco-ios

On the image below, IS-IS does not appear in "router ?" commands. However, configuration guides on YT videos and other sources would always proceed to "router isis" command, but it is just not available on my end.
[Screenshot of "router ?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi2Ch.png)

I tried using different routers; typing other IS-IS command variations such as "router is-is" or "router is is". My classmates and I have also searched for solutions from a multitude of different sources. None of which seem to have our problem; thus, we cannot find any solution regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This means either your image does not support it (need a service provider image AFAIK), or the router has been configured to not allow for your user type.